How to schedule Instagram Reel via the API?
I am using Meta graph api
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/#reels-posts
and it is working fine for publishing reels immediately.
I don't see in the documentation of any mention of how to schedule the reel at a particular time. (In contrast, you can do this for facebook reels by using scheduled_publish_time
I read online that this should be possible for Instagram as well https://business.instagram.com/blog/instagram-api-features-updates
Question
Can you guide me with one example of how to schedule Instagram reel via API ?
Two more optional ones

(Optional) Can I upload video from my local to instagram ? In the docs they require video_url, but for facebook api I can also upload data from local file
(Optional) Is it possible to cross-post in instagram-facebook, same way we can do via Meta Business Suite

Thanks in advance

Have you tried if using scheduled_publish_time the same way as you would for Facebook, works by any chance? If not, it might simply be that this is not available to regular developers - after all, the article you refer to as proof this was possible, says "To get started with scheduling posts, please work with one of our Facebook Marketing Partners or Instagram Partners." - which could mean, that it is only available to/via those.
